# Install Ubuntu side by side with Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, system-installation

I'm trying to setup both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop on the same machine.

I've partitioned the disk into 3 parts, so that I can have

- Windows
- Ubuntu
- Shared Partition for Files

I've installed Windows 7 on the first partition (which created a small partition of 100MB for boot), so now I have 4 partitions on the disk which is all it can take.

Now I am installing Ubuntu, and it's asking me whether I want to:

- Install Ubuntu inside Windows 7
- Replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu (No!)
- Something else

I want the Ubuntu installation to go into the partition that I prepared for it.  Should I choose "Something else"?  If I do so -- will I be able to choose which OS to load at boot?

Can anyone explain how "Ubuntu inside Windows" work?  it says that it will allow me to choose which OS to load at boot, which is desired.

---

**UPDATE:**

When choosing "Something else" I see also an option for Device for Boot Loader Installation:

- /dev/sda -- the ssd disk itself
- /dev/sda1 -- the Windows 7 loader (100MB partition)
- /dev/sda4 -- which is one of the other partitions

Which one should I choose there?

TIA!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 7 side by side with Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304592/windows-7-side-by-side-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @Virusboy - I disagree. I looked at the referenced question before posting this one. it does not answer my question.

Comment: Read it again, your in WUBI, not the live Boot.  Use that link to follow the instruction and you wont have an issue.

Comment: @Virusboy - my questions are simple. if you had utilized your time to answer instead of referring me to another question that shows how to repair a bad installation instead of making the right choices and avoiding the bad installation in the first place.

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336749/preparing-a-disk-from-windows-for-installing-ubuntu-partitioning/336757#336757

Comment: Systems only boot from MBR of a drive or sda in your case. Installing to a NTFS partition damages Windows and should not even be allowed. Only if you had another Linux with grub might you install to a Linux partition, more so it really is not used but would continue to update.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing "Something else" and selecting the same device to which I installed Ubuntu as the Boot Loader device.

Then I logged into Windows and installed [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) and pointed it to the partition to which I installed the Boot Loader (which in my case is the same one to which I installed Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, choose "Something else" there can you choose the partition where you want Ubuntu 14.04 installed.

Comment: wow! that was quick :) but will I be able to choose OS at boot?

Comment: Grub will add a Windows entry to its menu. You should just delete the partition you created for Ubuntu as it really wants two one for / (root) formated ext4 and one for swap which does not have a format. If you have an available primary, it then can be the extended partition and you can have as many logical partitions as you want. Ubuntu boots from logical partitions without issue.

Comment: @oldfred - thanks. can you please see my Update in the question and recommend the correct choice there?  I'm unfamiliar with Grub etc.

Comment: Posted in wrong answer, see above.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new partition and leave new partition unformatted. Then reboot and insert Ubuntu 14.04 DVD (burned from iso)
and choose **Something else option**.

[image: instruction]

Then choose unformatted partition on which you want to install Ubuntu. **Create new of Ext4 file-system and mount point /**

[image: instruction]

Then Ubuntu will be installed on that partition **be sure boot loader is in `/dev/sda`**

[image: instruction]

For selection swap area use any partition (split any one and create further 2GB is enough) format it as swap area.[image]

**After installing Ubuntu you can select between Ubuntu and Windows to boot at GRUB menu.**

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/456464/280643)

Answer (score 1):

There is two ways to install the bootloader (GRUB) .

1. In HDD itself (usually /dev/sda)
   This scenario is used when your HDD is formatted as MBR (Master Boot Record) partition table.
   Here is my old laptop partition table which is following MBR
   [image]
   In this case, the bootloader installed in HDD itself not in partition.
2. In separate partition called EFI.
   This scenario is used if your HDD is follows GPT (GUID Partition Table), depends on your firmware (BIOS/UEFI).
   Here is the partition looks like:
   [image] 
   The first partition (/dev/sda1) is where boot loader installed. And the last partition is 'shared' partition where i put my data and can be accessed through 3 OS.

It's seems your HDD is MBR formatted. So you can choose to install the bootloader in HDD itself (/dev/sda).